# GitFlow pluggin and VisualStudio slowness

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-flow

I have done some tests with GIT and VisualStudio, and when I use GitFlow pluggin, always when I try to do some action I got first this message in the output:

> The command is taking longer than expected

Then after some time I got this, as an error message in Visual Studio

> The command 'git flow feature start "SOMEFEATURE"' is taking longer than expected. You might be prompted for information such as credentials. Please run the command from command line to find out what is blocking the process

I makes the Git repositories useless for us, as we must wait for each simple command more than one minute, and it become quite useless for us to use git and gitflow. Someone knows what could be a cause for that, seems that it tries to process lot of content but it happens in any simple and fresh repository I create here.

Comment: Did you ever discover a resolution for this?

Comment: It got faster when I changed my home drive to a local folder, I had a shared folder instead. Also, we are using SSH, now it is with a decent speed now,